# Basic Python - print from for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, read-eval-print-loop

I created this list

```
bikes = ['trek','redline','giant']
```

and now am executing this simple for loop

```
for bike in bikes:
    print(bike)
```

why is this my output?

```
>>> for bike in bikes:
...     print(bike)
...
```

I expected the console to print out each value from the list.

Please help!

Comment: you are not running it properly

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: It will print if you hit enter again

Comment: You haven't ended the block yet, so it isn't running.

Comment: I'm able to print output. please elaborate your error. you need to press enter .

Comment: Press enter again, it will run.

Comment: Oh thanks! That works - why did I have to hit enter again? Why didn't it work when I selected the block of code and ran it?

Comment: The REPL had no way of knowing the `print` statement was the only thing in your loop.  For all it knew you were going to type `ride(bike)` on the next line. It waits for a blank line to know you're done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To run a file you must:

- Write out your code in a text editor.
- Save the file with the extension ".py" eg. `loopingThroughAList.py`
- Run the file from the command-line or if in IDLE select `Run > Run modulue`.

The command for Windows is

```
python -3 loopingThroughAList.py
```

You must also be in the same directory as the file to run it with the command above.

Hope this helped!

**EDIT**: You are facing this problem because you haven't ended your for loop. When running code from the console you need to enter twice to end loops and functions.